# Binding in Razor page with Kendo

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui

I'm trying to get to grips with `kendo` binding in MVVM.

I have a Razor page that looks like this...

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<div id="frm">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
 <div class="form-group">
    <label><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Username"/></label>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
 }

 <label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Username" /> 
</label>
 </div>

<script>
    var raw = @Html.Raw(Model.Me.ToJson());
    var vm = new kendo.observable(raw);
    kendo.bind($("#frm"), vm);
</script>
```

Index.cshtml.cs...

```
public class IndexModel : PageModelBase
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Person Me { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Me = new Person { Username = "Bobby Brown" };
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        var p = Me;

        p.Username += ".";
    }


    public class Person
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string ToJson() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

When I render the page, the 2 inputs are, properly bound to the passed in value from the server-side model.

When I change the value in one of the inputs client-side and change focus, the other input changes.

I expect all of this.

When I click the button, the control returns to the server and executes the code in `OnPost()`.

What doesn't happen is for `Me` to be set to something other than `null`.

I've tried it as is shown above,

I've tried refactoring the `OnPost()` method to `OnPost(Person me)` but `me` isn't set.

I've tried assessing the `Request.Form` object but there is nothing there.

I'm sure it must be simpler than I'm trying to make it.

Can anyone offer any advice about that I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I'm dim.

I worked it out. I was trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

I added a hidden input in the form with the name `Me` to match the property name I was binding to.

I changed the button to a regular button (from a `submit` button) and added an `onClick` handler that did this...

```
function submitForm() {
    $("#Me").val({ Username: vm.get("Username") });
    $("#frm").submit();
}
```

And "lo, there was light".

Thanks for listening